# How to have a popup calendar in a date view exposed filter?

Tags: 8, views, datetime

I am setting up a view, with the *Authored on* filter exposed. When selecting the box, there isn't any popup calendar.

Doesn't Drupal 8 come with a calendar popup in core? How can I turn this on for exposed filters with date?

Comment: Check if calendar module is enabled

Comment: How do you solve the problem?

Comment: try the date module or if not do it manually using a js library for date popups

Comment: Finally how do you solved the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with the [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module.

Enable the module, set it as the exposed form handler under Advanced -> Exposed form style, on the BEF settings page dialog set the filter display option to "jQuery UI Datepicker". Save everything and you should be good to go.

Note that changing from the default date format may require you to implement `hook_better_exposed_filters_display_options_alter`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Single Date Time Picker](https://www.drupal.org/project/single_datetime) module.

> Date time picker form element using the xdan jQuery Plugin Date and
>   Time Picker library - https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker.
>
> It supports date/time and date fields. You can use it on Datetime and
>   Datetime Range fields.

Comment: AFAICT that doesn't do anything for views filters, only entity field widgets.